# Inconsistent behavior in Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Very strange thing happened in my project, i have a pretty simple `CLR` objects,
First one is the `Model` other is `ViewModel`, after i compile the project i run my `WebApi ASP.NET` project, with the required parameters, i can see that my `Model` return with data.

Once i can see the Mapper did mapping ok, and the second time it's return every thing with nulls. 
The problem that is not happens all the time.

**Very Important: Update 14.03.2013**
***It's stop doing it when i recycle application, 
but after a while it's start doing it again, i re-save the `web.config` file 
then it's ok again.***

Here is my Model/ViewModel:

```
public class Gallery : Entity
{
    public override long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Settings SiteOwner { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string TitleDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual string GalleryTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UIItem> GalleryItems { get; set; }
}

public class UIItem : Entity
{
    public override long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Gallery Gallery { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Price { get; set; }
    public virtual string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string FileUrl { get; set; }
}
public class GalleryViewModel
{
    public virtual string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string TitleDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual string GalleryTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UIItemViewModel> GalleryItems { get; set; }
}

public class UIItemViewModel
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Price { get; set; }
    public virtual string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string FileUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the way i use it

```
// my apicontroller

// FindGalleryByAppIdAndCategoryId returns => Gallery 
var source = _galleryRepository.FindGalleryByAppIdAndCategoryId(appId, catId);
return Mapper.DynamicMap<GalleryViewModel>(source);
```

Comment: can you please mention the return type of FindGalleryByAppIdAndCategoryId OR what exact type is source

Comment: Fixed it in the question

Comment: please check that when you are getting null values in the galleryViewModel the source that you are passing in isn't null

Comment: Yes i have checked it and the result is always good that contains objects

Comment: Do you think i will ask a question without checking it?

Comment: make sure if you are using any context object make sure it is not going out of scope

Comment: and though I was pretty sure you must have checked it I was just ruling out a probability

Comment: @IamStalker If you don't give us this information, we don't know it; I found the question of Parv Sharma a very good one.

Comment: I have answered him! I just asked him if he thought that before i post a question to SO, I wouldn't check it before?

Comment: Where do you create the map? (CreateMap) I mean, can you try to use CreateMap/Map instead of DynamicMap? It will be faster too.

Comment: In a different assembly. Can you show an example of CreateMap/Map on my example?

Comment: check http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.be/2012/03/aspnet-mvc-using-automapper.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this happens in cases, when Gallery and UIItem have cross references:

```
public class Gallery : Entity
{
    public virtual IList<UIItem> GalleryItems { get; set; }
}

public class UIItem : Entity
{
    public virtual Gallery Gallery { get; set; }
}
```

Can you please test this case in your code?

Comment: Yes i will test it but one problem i do not map it to the DomainModel to DomainModel i map to ViewModel

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce erroneous behaviour

Answer (score 3):

1. Why did you marked your non-navigational properties with `virtual` keyword? Only properties, which involved in relations one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many and complex types can be marked with `virtual` keyword to apply *lazy loading*.

2.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UIItem,UIItemViewModel>();
...
UIItemViewModel result = Mapper.Map<UIItem,UIItemViewModel>(your UIItem);
```

If you need special mapping logic, you can do like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UIItem,UIItemViewModel>().ConvertUsing(new ModelToViewModelConverter());
...
UIItemViewModel result = Mapper.Map<UIItem,UIItemViewModel>(your UIItem);
...
```

Converter will be look like this:

```
public class ModelToViewModelConverter : ITypeConverter<UIItem,UIItemViewModel>
    {
        public UIItemViewModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            UIItem item = (UIItem)context.SourceValue;
            // Perform your convertion logic 
        }
    }
```

In the same way you can map all of your entities even collection to collection.

Comment: Indeed what I was thinking, im not sure why he's relying on the DynamicMap if its not actually necessary. I would only use Dynamic in dire situations

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using

```
Mapper.Map<Source,Destination>(source);
```

or

```
Mapper.Map(source);
```

and ensure you have declared a

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

I don't see your reason for using Dynamic Map when you can declare a CreateMap of the two types. You shouldn't experience this behaviour doing it this way.